# How to configure root kde same as user?

Tags: linux, kde, root, suse

Eclipse looks completely different when run under root compared to my user.

It's like kde wasn't setup for root upon installation.

I'm running Suse 9.3 Pro.

How do I configure root kde so that eclipse looks the same when run as user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it is a bad practice to run a user application like Eclupse as root.

If you want to take the risk, you can always boot to single user mod, log in as root through the console and `startx` from there. Once you setup the KDE theme, you can switch runlevel to normal.

Comment: well how am
I
supposed to debug an application from within eclipse that needs to be run as root?

Comment: Yeah, that will be quite painful. If you want more security, you may want to setup "remote" debugging through sockets, so your Eclipse runs as a normal user. Otherwise enter single user or rescue mode (normally an option at your boot loader menu) so you can log-in as root before the X server is started. Of course, if you know your root password you may be able to log-in directly.

Comment: actually the remote debugging sounds like the best idea, separating the user run eclipse used to debug and the root application